# Cannot launch UR5 simulation in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, universal-robot, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to launch a simulation of the UR5 in gazebo with the command `roslaunch ur_gazebo ur5.launch`. I am getting a number of errors including

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [pr2_mechanism_diagnostics/pr2_mechanism_diagnostics]: pr2_mechanism_diagnostics
```

and

```
[ERROR] [1412703963.702016682, 0.508000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/shoulder_pan_joint
```

and

```
[ERROR] [1412703964.014360175, 0.760000000]: Could not find joint 'shoulder_pan_joint' in 'hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface'.
[ERROR] [1412703964.014464269, 0.760000000]: Failed to initialize the controller
[ERROR] [1412703964.014512292, 0.760000000]: Initializing controller 'arm_controller' failed
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1412703965.015916] [1.759000] Failed to load arm_controller
```

I had previously messed around with the UR5 in simulation around June, and it worked fine (though the PID gains were a bit off). Has anyone else had this problem? Have you figured out how to fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194415/cannot-launch-ur5-simulation-in-gazebo/) by [rkeatin3](https://answers.ros.org/users/19735/rkeatin3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2014-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If this is a source install, you might want to run `rosdep check ..` on the `ur_gazebo` package. `pr2_mechanism_diagnostics` is a run dependency, as stated in the [package.xml](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/blob/hydro-devel/ur_gazebo/package.xml#L56).

If you installed `ur_gazebo` using the Debians, please submit a bug report at [universal_robot/issues](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/issues).

Could you update your question with the relevant information?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rkeatin3](https://answers.ros.org/users/19735/rkeatin3/) on 2014-10-09**:
Thanks. I've submitted the bug report.